How to exclude a Folder in AdvancedSecurity in Azure in a Java project
We use Azure Devops and build our Java project there. We also use the AdvancedSecurity. Now i try to exclude a folder from the Scanner.
I have found in AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1 the parameter "codeqlpathstoignore" but this does not work for Java. Docu
How else can i achieve this.
Cheers T

What I can gather from the documentation, it seems that the setting should work to a some degree with Java (and C#) if the code is not built, so using buildtype: None should help.
This GitHub Issue links to GitHub Advanced Security documentation (that is the thing that is used underneath)
More information about settings
